# False Unused Import Statement in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Given this scenario:

`b.py`:

```py
import A
# A is unused here
```

`c.py`:

```py
from b import A
# A is used here
```

PyCharm complains in `b.py` that `import A` is an unused import and Optimize imports deletes it, breaking import in `c.py`.

I know these chained imports are not a good practice (although you may use it to implement a facade module), but is it me or is it a PyCharm fail?

Comment: It's you. If you want to work around this IDE behaviour just add an `if False:` block where you use those variables so that the Optimize imports wont touch them.

Comment: I am working on an existing code in a large project. Also, I don't find it a good idea to write code for the sake of the IDE. It's noise, especially for contributors using other tools.

Comment: "Fail" is a bit harsh, a minor shortcoming yes, but there's not really any way to get 100% correct behaviour easily (you can obfuscate the use of A as much as you please).  If A gets removed when it shouldn't have, this is the kind of problem your buildbot / jenkins / continuous integration setup should pick up in a flash

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I can tell this behaviour is *not* handled as an inspection or some other configurable option, which means there is no `#noinspection UnusedImport` (or equivalent) that can be placed before the imports.

If you don't want to define an unused block where you use those variables there's an other simple and probably better way to achieve what you want:

```
#b.py code
import A

# [...] your code


__all__ = ['A', ...]  # *all* the names you want to export
```

PyCharm is smart enough to look at `__all__` and avoid removing `A` as unused import.
However there's a limitation that `__all__` must be a simple list literal. You *cannot* do things like:

```
__all__ = ['A'] + [name for name in iterable if condition(name)]
```

Not even:

```
x = 'b'
__all__ = ['A', x]
```

Defining `__all__` is a best-practice to make your module `*`-import safe anyway, so is something you should already do.

Answer (score 104):

You can actually use the `PyUnresolvedReferences` marker to deactivate the inspection for your import statement:

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import A
```

Reference: [PyCharm bug PY-2240](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-2240)

Comment: This solved my issue! Your answer helped me find a comprehensive list with all markers, at http://codeoptimism.com/blog/pycharm-suppress-inspections-list/

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the right noinspection. I haz a sad that the link to codeoptimism isn't working anymore, a list would be great.

This seems like a better targeted answer than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Scott – I found a new link https://github.com/whitews/pc-inspection-suppression-list if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
from C import A, B
_ = (A, B); del _
```

Works for me. I don't like

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
```

as it would give false negatives in case A cannot be imported. And

```
__all__ = ['A', 'B', ...]
```

is cryptic and is not convenient for refactoring.