# Django - unused import statement

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner to Django and currently undertaking the codeacademy 'build web apps with django course'. To help better understand django and python I decided to use Pycharm rather than the website interface. I've setup my project, ran the server, migrated and setup an app called 'randomfortune'. I'm now up to the step where I create a view function in views.py:

```
def myview(request):
return request, 'randomfortune/fortune.html'
```

In urls.py I use the below imports but I get an error saying 'unused import statement'.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
```

I done some searching previously and my venv does point to python.exe and it still doesnt work can anybody help out as I'm stuck to the point that I cant continue with the course.

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139329/false-unused-import-statement-in-pycharm

Comment: This is not an error, this won't prevent your code from running. PyCharm just informs you that your code contains an useless import, as you don't make any use of what you imported. Remove the useless import or let PyCharm complain about it...